# Why do some of my accordions have smaller text on mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
body {
  font-family: 'work sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #999;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #010101;
  background: url(https://imgur.com/YRl8KNP.png) center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: left;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 3px;
  height: 3px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: #000;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #010101;
}

a:link,
a:visited,
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999;
}

#header {
  padding: 160px;
}

.h_title {
  font: 150px 'work sans';
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 45px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.h_menu {
  border-top: 1px solid #999;
  width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 0;
  margin-bottom: 175px;
}

.h_top {
  text-align: right;
  font: 12px 'work sans';
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.h_top::before {
  content: '////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////';
  font: 11px 'arial';
  font-weight: 400;
  display: block;
  color: #ff00ff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}

.h_tabs input {
  display: none;
}

.h_tabs {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 230px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.h_tabs label {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 20px;
  font: 9px 'work sans';
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: crosshair;
}

.h_tabs label:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: 90px;
}

.h_tabs label:nth-of-type(3) {
  top: 160px;
}

.h_tabs label b {
  color: #ff00ff;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.h_tabs label span {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.h_tabs label:after {
  content: '001';
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: right;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.6s;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.h_tabs label:nth-of-type(2):after {
  content: '002';
}

.h_tabs label:nth-of-type(3):after {
  content: '003';
}

.h_tabs input:checked+label span {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.h_tabs input:checked+label::after {
  width: 0;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.h_tab1,
.h_tab2 {
  width: 700px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.h_blurb {
  font: 14px 'work sans';
  color: #ccc;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.h_cont {
  background: #171717;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.h_nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  margin: 0 35px 15px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 6px;
  font: 12px 'share tech mono';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #aaa;
}

.h_nav a::after {
  content: '';
  width: 15px;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -1px;
  background: #ff00ff;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.h_nav a:nth-of-type(2n):after {
  background: #ff00ff;
}

.h_nav a:nth-of-type(3n):after {
  background: #ff00ff;
}

.h_nav a:hover:after {
  width: 180px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#htab1:checked~.h_tab1,
#htab2:checked~.h_tab2 {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
}

#lean_overlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/zdXP0Uo.jpg) center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  display: none;
}

#Pages #wrapper {
  background: transparent;
}

#page_container {
  width: 1100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 15px 0;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.page_menu {
  font: 12px 'share tech mono';
  width: 220px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-left: 12px;
  float: left;
}

.page_menu a:active {
  color: #ff00ff;
}

.page_menu h1 {
  font: 17px 'work sans';
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 30px 0 10px 0;
}

.page_menu h1:before {
  content: '/ ';
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: #ccc;
}

.page_content {
  background: #171717;
  width: 705px;
  float: left;
  outline: 1px solid rgb(255 255 255 / 0.2);
  outline-offset: 10px;
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 150%;
}

.page_content h1 {
  font: 50px 'work sans';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.page_content h2 {
  font: 15px 'share tech mono';
  text-transform: lowercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 10px 0;
  color: #ff00ff;
}

.page_text {
  padding: 20px 50px;
}

.page_text u {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.page_em {
  margin-top: 25px;
  font: 12px 'share tech mono';
  line-height: 17px;
  border: #333 solid 1px;
  padding: 30px;
}

.page_em u {
  color: #ff00ff;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: 17px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.page_menu ol {
  counter-reset: item;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.page_menu li ol {
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.page_menu b {
  color: #ff00ff;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.page_menu ol li {
  display: block;
}

.page_menu li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
  counter-increment: item;
  font-size: 9px;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: #ff00ff;
}

.sub_canons li {
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  font: 7px 'work sans';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.sub_canons {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 30px 0;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.sub_canons li b {
  display: block;
  font: 10px 'share tech mono';
}

.page_content h3 {
  font: 14px 'share tech mono';
  text-align: right;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  color: #fff;
  counter-increment: faqcounter;
}

.page_content h3::before {
  content: '00' counter(faqcounter, decimal-leading-zero);
  margin-right: 12px;
  color: #ff00ff;
}

.page_content h4 {
  font: 13px 'share tech mono';
  text-transform: lowercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  color: #fff;
  counter-increment: faqcounter;
}

.page_content h4::before {
  content: '00' counter(faqcounter, decimal-leading-zero);
  margin-right: 10px;
  color: #ff1053;
}

.page_content h5 {
  font: 13px 'share tech mono';
  text-transform: lowercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  color: #fff;
  counter-increment: faqcounter;
}

.page_content h5::before {
  content: '00' counter(faqcounter, decimal-leading-zero);
  margin-right: 10px;
  color: #4592f7;
}

.page_content h6 {
  font: 13px 'share tech mono';
  text-transform: lowercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  color: #fff;
  counter-increment: faqcounter;
}

.page_content h6::before {
  content: '00' counter(faqcounter, decimal-leading-zero);
  margin-right: 10px;
  color: #ff5f32;
}

a.user-tagged.mgroup-4 {
  color: #744dba;
}

a.user-tagged.mgroup-8 {
  color: #ff1053;
}

a.user-tagged.mgroup-6 {
  color: #4592f7;
}

a.user-tagged.mgroup-7 {
  color: #ff5f32;
}

.iconpad {
  padding: 10px;
  border: #222 solid 1px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.padex {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
}

::-moz-selection {
  color: #ff00ff;
}

::selection {
  color: #ff00ff;
}

faqentry {
  font: 12px 'share tech mono';
  width: 220px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-top: 55px;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  float: left;
}

faqentry ol li {
  margin: 10px 15px 10px 10px;
  padding-left: 1px;
  font-size: 9px;
  color: #ff00ff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .accordion {
      font-family: 'share tech mono';
      font-size: 14px;
      text-align: justify;
      text-transform: lowercase;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
      margin: 20px -5px 0px -5px;
      color: #fff;
      background: none;
      border: none;
      transition: 0.4s;
      counter-increment: faqcounter;
    }
    
    .accordion:focus {
      outline: 0 !important;
    }
    
    .accordion::before {
      content: '00' counter(faqcounter, decimal-leading-zero);
      margin-right: 12px;
      color: #ff00ff;
    }
    
    div.panel {
      margin-top: 10px;
      border: #333 solid 1px;
      display: block;
      max-height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: 0.2s ease-out;
    }
    
    .panel__content {
      padding: 30px;
      line-height: 170%;
    }
  </style>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="HERE">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:100,400,700,900|Share+Tech+Mono" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>STICTION</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="STICTION.css" TYPE="text/css">
</head>

<div id="header">
  <div class="h_title">stiction</div>
  <div class="h_menu">
    <div class="h_top"></div>
    <div class="h_tabs">

      <input id="htab1" type="radio" name="htabs" checked>
      <label for="htab1"><span>CANDY TEETH, NEON IDIOTS.</span> <b>/</b></label>

      <input id="htab2" type="radio" name="htabs">
      <label for="htab2"><span>OTHER LINKS</span> <b>/</b></label>

      <div class="h_tab1">
        <div class="h_blurb"><i>Welcome to the new world; myth meets the future. Where do you fit in?</i><br><br>
          <span style="text-transform: uppercase; font-family: share tech mono; font-size: 11px;">literate supernatural and cyberpunk group roleplay set in City 0215 during the year 2447.</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="h_tab2">
        <div class="h_nav">
          <a href="https://discord.gg/2Rrw9QB">DISCORD</a>
          <a href="http://GOOGLELINKHERE.com">DIRECTORY</a>
          <a href="https://open.spotify.com/playlist/1euBOWkTE7hnMCsPgBFlqM">PLAYLIST</a>


        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="page_container">


    <div class="page_menu">
      <ol>
        <li><a href="/PAGETITLE.html">INDEX</a></li>
      </ol>
      <h1>ESSENTIAL READS</h1>
      <ol>
        <li><a href="/PAGETITLE.html">QUICK-START GUIDE</a></li>
        <li><a href="/RULES.html">RULES</a></li>
        <li><a href="/PAGETITLE.html">HISTORY</a></li>
        <li><a href="/PAGETITLE.html">SETTING</a></li>
        <li><a href="/PAGETITLE.html">SPECIES</a></li>
        <ol>
          <li><a href="/PAGETITLE.html">LIVING</a></li>
          <li><a href="/PAGETITLE.html">DECEASED</a></li>
          <li><a href="/PAGETITLE.html">PURGATORIC</a></li>
        </ol>
      </ol>
      <h1>IN-DEPTH CONTENT</h1>
      <ol>

        <li><span style="color: #ff00ff; font-weight: bold;">FAQ</span></li>
        <li><a href="/PAGETITLE.html">SUBPLOTS</a></li>
        <ol>
          <li><a href="/PAGETITLE.html">SUBPLOT 001</a></li>
          <li><a href="/PAGETITLE.html">SUBPLOT 002</a></li>
          <li><a href="/PAGETITLE.html">SUBPLOT 003</a></li>
        </ol>
        <li><a href="/PAGETITLE.html">OFFICIAL SERVER FACTIONS</a></li>
        <li><a href="/PAGETITLE.html">MEMBER-CREATED FACTIONS</a></li>

      </ol>
    </div>

    <div class="page_content">

      <div class="page_text" id="top">
        <h1>lore questions</h1>


        <div class="page_em"><u>A NOTE</u> This world- the world of <u style="color : #fff;
text-transform : uppercase;
font-weight : 700;
letter-spacing : 1px;
text-decoration : none;
font-size : 12px;">STICTION</u>- isn't just the project and product of the staff team. We want you to feel that you can contribute to this world! To that end, these are all questions that guests and members have asked in the server. Questions are either
          answered according to existing/established lore, or (in cases where the staff team hasn't thought of said situation or scenario) are talked out with members to come to a satisfying answer.
          <p>
            This page is updated regularly, so make sure you keep an eye on it!
            <p>

              It's probably easiest to explore this page using the <b>CRTL+F</b> function, especially if you have specific questions. There are also quick links to help you find relevant sections faster.</div>

        <faqentry id="quick links">
          <ol>
            <li><a href="#section"><u>world-building</u></a></li>
            <li><a href="#section2"><u>subplots</u></a></li>
            <li><a href="#section3"><u>species-specific</u></a>
              <ol>
                <li><a href="#abilities"><u>general abilities</u></a></li>
                <li><a href="#witches"><u>witches</u></a></li>
                <li><a href="#shifters"><u>shifters</u></a></li>
                <li><a href="#vampires"><u>vampires</u></a></li>
                <li><a href="#reapers"><u>reapers</u></a></li>
                <li><a href="#ghosts"><u>ghosts</u></a></li>
                <li><a href="#phoenixes"><u>phoenixes</u></a></li>
                <li><a href="#familiars"><u>familiars</u></a></li>
                <li><a href="#androids"><u>androids</u></a></li>
              </ol>
          </ol>
        </faqentry>

        <Br><br>

        <h3>context clues</h3>
        Before you get started exploring this new world, it's helpful to keep in mind a few things to help you get a feel for everything. (It might even help you answer your own questions, who knows?)
        <p>
          The first bit of info you'll need is that electricity and all other forms of energy are obsolete; instead, the world runs on <i>magic</i> which is "refined" into modern power. That leads into point two, which is that supernatural/magic creatures
          are no longer monsters under the bed, or creatures in the shadow; they live open, public lives.
          <p>
            Since this is a cyberpunk site, it stands to reason that technology is significantly more advanced than what we have now. It's not so advanced that regular interstellar travel exists, but it's so much farther ahead that paper (and privacy, most sickness,
            and rustic creature comforts for that matter) is a thing of the past. Every person on the planet is in some way connected to the Global Communications Lattice (or GCL for short), and everything on the planet is connected/hooked up/linked to
            it.
            <p>
              As far as specific pieces of technology go, that's largely up to you, your ideas, and genre standards.
              <p>

                It never hurts to ask an admin or run an idea by us before executing an idea, though!<br><br>
                <a name="section">&nbsp;</a>
                <h2>world-building</h2>
                <button class="accordion">What's the primary language spoken in City 0215? What about the rest of the world?</button>
                <div class="panel">
                  <div class="panel__content">English, Russian, and Chinese are the most common languages spoken in City 0215, though Czech isn't uncommon.
                    <p>

                      English has become the global <i>lingua franca</i>, but thanks to freely accessible knowledge, every language (even dead languages) can be learned now! Linguistic diversity not only still exists in this world, but is flourishing;
                      most people know more than one language, and those that don't have a universal translator.</div>
                </div>

                <button class="accordion">What's the internet like now?</button>
                <div class="panel">
                  <div class="panel__content">The internet has become integral to every single facet of life. People still call it the internet, but it's official name is the <u>Global Communication Lattice</u>, or <u>GCL</u> for short. Some people also call it <u>the rabbithole</u>,
                    given its tendency to consume people’s entire lives. In true opportunistic capitalist fashion, the official mascot of the GCL (and the new Clippy) is a little white rabbit.
                    <p>
                      It looks relatively the same in 2447 as it did in the twenty-first century; video streaming and vlogging exists, social media is still around, and everything you could possibly want is online. It's also much more, with literally anything you could need
                      or want to do at the tips of your fingers.</div>
                </div>
                
                <script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
</script>
```

I've created some accordion questions on a webpage, and they work perfectly fine on desktop. When switched to mobile, though, questions that only use one line of text appear smaller in font size than the questions that have two or more lines.

I've tried using the meta tag for dynamic scaling, but it doesn't affect the questions that appear smaller.

Essentially, I'd like every question to appear in 14px font rather than shorter questions looking smaller on mobile.

EDIT: I've added a Snippet, including all my CSS (unfortunately) since I genuinely don't know what element(s) might be affecting it. I've included a long question and a short question to show the issue in comparison.

```html
<button class="accordion">What is healthcare like?</button>
<div class="panel">
  <div class="panel__content">Healthcare, considered an inalienable human right, is standardized and freely available. Nearly every street corner has a "doc-in-a-box" station, where a person can step inside a metal tube and be diagnosed/healed.<p>
      That being said, complicated issues- like debris in wounds, chronic diseases, or anything else involved- still require actual physicians. Large hospitals still exist, but they're less common and really only suited for emergencies or critical situations.<p>
          Unfortunately, it's still true that the more money you have, the quicker and better quality your care is.
      </div>
</div>
```

```css
<style>
.accordion {
    font-family: 'share tech mono';
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: justify;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin: 20px -5px 0px -5px;
    color: #fff;
 background: none;
 border: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
  counter-increment : faqcounter;
}

.accordion:focus {outline:0 !important;}

.accordion::before  {
content : '00' counter(faqcounter,decimal-leading-zero);
margin-right : 12px;
color : #ff00ff;
}

div.panel {
  margin-top: 10px;
    border : #333 solid 1px;
    display:block;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}

.panel__content {
  padding:30px;
    line-height: 170%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Most likely there's other css affecting your text. The one in the post doesn't show anything that would be making it smaller

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve]? From your description and the provided code, chances are we're dealing with an optical illusion.

Comment: @jord, it's great you added the example, but it appears we use different definitions for *"minimal"*. What should we be looking at?

Comment: I genuinely don't know is the problem. This is my first time working with accordions so I've been slinging stuff at the wall and seeing what sticks. I had a few other people add to the code and I'm not even sure what they changed to get the initial accordions where they are now (which is totally my mistake but hopefully this is salvageable without restarting the whole thing).

Comment: If we're talking about the `button.accordion`s (first one having this `innerText`: *"What's the primary language spoken in City 0215? What about the rest of the world?"*), I can assure you they all have `font-size: 14px` on both desktop and mobile. (It can be inspected). It's an optical illusion.

Comment: It could very well be my own mobile device, honestly. The "large" question numbers also briefly flicker and change sizes when clicked, and I've read that some iOS devices have issues with accordions (such as not opening the accordion fully in one click) which I'm also experiencing on my phone.

Comment: Adding `<meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">` to the `<head>` section should fix your problem. Place it before the first `<style>`.

Comment: @jord If the problem persists, do you think you can provide a screenshot of what you see on your phone? Also, what phone is it, and does the desktop browser have an emulation mode for that specific model?